# Designing an asp.net MVC app with ORM and future migration to NoSql

Tags: asp.net-mvc, orm, nosql, scalability

Just starting a new asp.net mvc solution and one of the requirements is the ability to scale for potentially millions of users at later stage.

I'm planning to use a generic repository that exposes IQuerable and use linq in the service/application level (I know It's not a pure DDD approach but this is not the debate :) ). I'm planning EF as ORM for dataaccess (with a distributed cache as second level cache to acheive the scalability at some extent)

The issue I will be facing is all those linq queries not compatible with any future NoSql linq provider (The Joins are unlikely to be supported in NoSql linq provider).
But I'm willing to take the risk of having to rethink all those linq queries as long as they are all located in one place : the service/application layer.

What would be a better approach?  any recommandation ?

Comment: Deal with scaleability once it becomes an actual issue. By then, you should have the resources to devote to worrying about it. For now, focus on getting the application delivered and in the hands of users.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A NoSQL database wont solve problems that a RDBMS can't. Only well designed tables can.

I would use a NoSQL solution like [RavenDb](http://ravendb.net/) (since you are in .NET) from the start to decrease the development time and not switch later on.

Use [CQRS](http://bit.ly/tqW2gD) if you want your application to scale. No need for an external query cache from start. Just do the interfaces so that you can switch to an external cache (or query DB as some call it) later on.